# How can I use DeviceOrientationEvent.webkitCompassHeading in unison with the associated beta and gamma values on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js

I have modified DeviceOrientationControls to be oriented north instead of the direction the device was in when it started up, and while it works on Android I am having difficulty getting the iOS version working. Here's my modified version

```
/**
 * @author richt / http://richt.me
 * @author WestLangley / http://github.com/WestLangley
 *
 * W3C Device Orientation control (http://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html)
 */

THREE.DeviceOrientationControls = function ( object ) {

    var scope = this;

    this.object = object;
    this.object.rotation.reorder( 'YXZ' );

    this.enabled = true;

    this.deviceOrientation = {};
    this.screenOrientation = 0;

    this.alphaOffset = 0; // radians
    this.absolute = false;
    this.alphaOffsetDevice = undefined;
    this.alphaOffsetScreen = undefined;

    var onDeviceOrientationChangeEvent = function ( event ) {
        if(scope.absolute) return;

        scope.deviceOrientation = event;

    };

    var onDeviceOrientationAbsoluteChangeEvent = function ( event ) {

        scope.deviceOrientation = event;
        scope.absolute = true;

    };

    var onScreenOrientationChangeEvent = function () {

        scope.screenOrientation = window.orientation || 0;

    };

    // The angles alpha, beta and gamma form a set of intrinsic Tait-Bryan angles of type Z-X'-Y''

    var setObjectQuaternion = function () {

        var zee = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );

        var euler = new THREE.Euler();

        var q0 = new THREE.Quaternion();

        var q1 = new THREE.Quaternion( - Math.sqrt( 0.5 ), 0, 0, Math.sqrt( 0.5 ) ); // - PI/2 around the x-axis

        return function ( quaternion, alpha, beta, gamma, orient ) {

            euler.set( beta, alpha, - gamma, 'YXZ' ); // 'ZXY' for the device, but 'YXZ' for us

            quaternion.setFromEuler( euler ); // orient the device

            quaternion.multiply( q1 ); // camera looks out the back of the device, not the top

            quaternion.multiply( q0.setFromAxisAngle( zee, - orient ) ); // adjust for screen orientation

        };

    }();

    this.connect = function () {

        onScreenOrientationChangeEvent(); // run once on load

        window.addEventListener( 'orientationchange', onScreenOrientationChangeEvent, false );
        window.addEventListener( 'deviceorientation', onDeviceOrientationChangeEvent, false );
        window.addEventListener( 'deviceorientationabsolute', onDeviceOrientationAbsoluteChangeEvent, false );

        scope.enabled = true;

    };

    this.disconnect = function () {

        window.removeEventListener( 'orientationchange', onScreenOrientationChangeEvent, false );
        window.removeEventListener( 'deviceorientation', onDeviceOrientationChangeEvent, false );
        window.removeEventListener( 'deviceorientationabsolute', onDeviceOrientationAbsoluteChangeEvent, false );

        scope.enabled = false;

    };

    this.update = function () {
        if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

        var device;
        device = scope.deviceOrientation;

        if ( device ) {

            var alpha = this.getDirection() ? THREE.Math.degToRad( this.getDirection() ) + scope.alphaOffset : 0; // Z

            var beta = device.beta ? THREE.Math.degToRad( device.beta ) : 0; // X'

            var gamma = device.gamma ? THREE.Math.degToRad( device.gamma ) : 0; // Y''

            var orient = scope.screenOrientation ? THREE.Math.degToRad( scope.screenOrientation ) : 0; // O

            setObjectQuaternion( scope.object.quaternion, alpha, beta, gamma, orient );

        }

    };

    this.dispose = function () {

        scope.disconnect();

    };

    this.iOSOrientationPermission = function ()
    {
    if (typeof DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
            DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission().then(permissionState => {
                if (permissionState === 'granted') {

                }

                console.log(permissionState);
            }).catch(console.error);
        }
    }

    this.getDirection = function ()
    {
        return (typeof scope.deviceOrientation.webkitCompassHeading != "undefined") ? scope.deviceOrientation.webkitCompassHeading : scope.deviceOrientation.alpha;
    }

    this.getDirectionMap = function ()
    {
        return (typeof scope.deviceOrientation.webkitCompassHeading != "undefined") ? (360 - scope.deviceOrientation.webkitCompassHeading) : scope.deviceOrientation.alpha;
    }

    this.connect();

};
```

I've replaced mentions of DeviceOrientationEvent.alpha in the DeviceOrientationControls with the function getDirection() which returns DeviceOrientationEvent.alpha on Android and DeviceOrientationEvent.webkitCompassHeading on iOS, but this does not work for iOS, instead it causes the scene camera to jolt around as the phone is rotated on it's Y axis, or when the phone is tilted past the horizon. I've found very little online on how to use the webkitCompassHeading value, and what little I did find suggested to have it replace the alpha value, which as stated above does not work in my case. It appears that the alpha/beta/gamma values are converted from a quaternion internally, while webkitCompassHeading is just a single isolated 0-360 value making it not so straight forward to use with the other values.

I have tried using a calibration function to grab the webkitCompassHeading on startup and using it to offset the alpha, but this only provided correct results about 50% of the time. Since on Android the alpha value is constantly being updated with the heading value internally I figured a similar way of doing things for iOS would be the best way to do it, but at this point I'm stumped. On Android I was using Google Chrome, and Safari on iOS.

Here's a couple links regarding the APIs I'm using

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondeviceorientation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondeviceorientationabsolute